# Parse JSON elements of a list returned from a multi-choice column in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, choice-field

How can I parse the below JSON in power automate to get the value of multi choice column '**MyChoice**'.

I am trying to parse it using expression **body('Parse_JSON_2')?['d']?['result']?[1]?['MyChoice']?['results']** but its not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the sample JSON:

```
{
    "body": {
        "d": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "",
                        "uri": "",
                        "type": ""
                    },
                    "CreatedBy": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            ""
                        }
                    },
                    "Fields": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "FileVersion": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "Created": "",
                    "**MyChoice**": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
                        },
                        "results": [
                            "choice1",
                             "choice2"
                        ]
                    },
                    ]
}
}
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your schema was generated. Tested with a Multi-Select choice column of a SPO list with the schema shown below (Note that schema has been manually modified from the output of [Get items])

In Power Automate, Multi-Select Choice column values are returned as an array, so need to treat them as an array as well.

**SPO List**
[image]

**Schema**

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "@@odata.etag": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ItemInternalId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ID": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "MyChoiceFruits": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "@@odata.type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "Value": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "@@odata.type",
                        "Id",
                        "Value"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        "required": [
                        "@@odata.etag",
                        "ItemInternalId",
                        "ID",
                        "MyChoiceFruits"
                    ]

    }
}
```

```
#Get first item's choice field values as an array

body('Parse_JSON')?[0]?['MyChoiceFruits']

#Get first item's first choice field's value. 

body('Parse_JSON')?[0]?['MyChoiceFruits']?[0]['Value']
```

**output**

[image]